# Powershell Script - Send Email Only When Drive Space Is Below MinThreshold

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-10

I'm using Windows 10 Enterprise 1709 and PowerShell version 5.0. I have this PowerShell script below that I found online. It works but I don't understand what a line in code is doing so I can decided how to edit it for what I need to do. Also, it sends an email even though the drive is not below minimum threshold. I would like to understand this line of the code and fix it to only send email alert when it reaches below the minimum threshold. `$freeSpaceGB = [Math]::Round([float]$disk.FreeSpace / 1073741824);`and this line `$computer = $computer.toupper();`

The entire code is below:

```
$minGbThreshold = 50GB

$computers = $env:COMPUTERNAME
$smtpAddress = "smtp.our-firm.com"
$toAddress = "anyone@anywhere.com"
$fromAddress = "desktop-admin@anywhere.com"

foreach($computer in $computers)
{    
    $disks = Get-WmiObject -ComputerName $computer -Class Win32_LogicalDisk -Filter "DriveType = 3";
    $computer = $computer.toupper();
    $deviceID = $disk.DeviceID;
    foreach($disk in $disks)
    {
        $freeSpaceGB = [Math]::Round([float]$disk.FreeSpace / 1073741824);
        if($freeSpaceGB -lt $minGbThreshold)
        {
            $smtp = New-Object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($smtpAddress)
            $msg = New-Object Net.Mail.MailMessage
            $msg.To.Add($toAddress)
            $msg.From = $fromAddress
            $msg.Subject = “Diskspace below threshold ” + $computer + "\" + $disk.DeviceId
            $msg.Body = $computer + "\" + $disk.DeviceId + " " + $freeSpaceGB + "GB Remaining";
            $smtp.Send($msg)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I now understand the math line and what it is doing. I still need to understand why I still get an email even though the disk space isn't below the minimum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally got a working script. Hope this helps others. This is the answer I was looking for.

```
$minGbThreshold = 29;
$computers = $env:COMPUTERNAME;
$smtpAddress = "smtp.yourdomain.com";
$toAddress = "anyemail@gmail.com";
$fromAddress = "anyotheremail@gmail.com";
foreach($computer in $computers)
{    
    $disks = Get-WmiObject -ComputerName $computer -Class Win32_LogicalDisk -Filter "DriveType = 3";
    $computer = $computer.toupper();
    $deviceID = $disk.DeviceID;
    foreach($disk in $disks)
    {
        $freeSpaceGB = [Math]::Round([float]$disk.FreeSpace / 1073741824, 2);
        if($freeSpaceGB -lt $minGbThreshold)
        {
            $smtp = New-Object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($smtpAddress)
            $msg = New-Object Net.Mail.MailMessage
            $msg.To.Add($toAddress)
            $msg.From = $fromAddress
            $msg.Subject = “Diskspace below threshold ” + $computer + "\" + $disk.DeviceId
            $msg.Body = $computer + "\" + $disk.DeviceId + " " + $freeSpaceGB + "GB Remaining";
            $smtp.Send($msg)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok so `$freeSpaceGB = [Math]::Round([float]$disk.FreeSpace / 1073741824);` is just rounding up your free drive space (in bits) to something readable (in this case GB's). So this way youre not getting a return like `120.237812042236`. This one `$computer = $computer.toupper();` is just turning all of the 'characters' to upper case letters.

As for why it is not doing what you expect it to with your if statement, you effectively are comparing a number that was converted to a readable form of GB as apposed to the total number of bits. so youre effectively asking if `120 -lt 53687091200`.

i would change 50gb to 50 or remove the conversion that happens later on.